# Why Nuget add reference without changing *.csproj file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am using Nuget to add some libraries. I found the *.csproj does not change after adding the new library, but the References is actually changed.

Anyone knows how Nuget manage references?

Comment: I am not sure for a *.csproj solution. But in the Web Application, nuget manages it inside my packages.config file. Maybe they have something similar in a *.csproj file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double-checked. The references are maintaing inside the *.config file.
Look at the Image below.

[image: Reference Image]

Inside the `packages.config` file you will see something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
</packages>
```

And inside the `App.config` file you will see something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=some-token" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Note:** The values in this example is just a sample value. Your solution may differ.

Comment: In Net Core it is not anymore in the config file, it's only in the csproj.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that the NuGet package references are stored in packages.config, NuGet does update the project file to add assembly references. Project file and assembly references are always managed in the project file.

In your case, it's possible that you already had referenced the same assemblies as the NuGet package (so it wouldn't have been modified), or maybe you inspected the version on disk before it was saved.

Comment: Yep, I didn't save the project file and this was my issue.